# Function for trigger (INSTEAD OF DELETE ON view) can't pick values from query [POSTGRESQL]

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

The function and relative trigger I made are as it follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unregister() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE 'Student: %, course: %.', NEW.student, NEW.course;
    IF (EXISTS (SELECT student FROM view_registered WHERE student = NEW.student AND course = NEW.course)) THEN
      DELETE FROM table_registered WHERE student = NEW.student AND course = NEW.course;
      RAISE NOTICE '% successfully unregistered from this course (%)!', NEW.student, NEW.course;
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION '% is not registered to this course (%)!', NEW.student, NEW.course;
    END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER unregister INSTEAD OF DELETE ON view_registered
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE unregister();
```

Since the beginning, I saw through the initial `RAISE NOTICE` that the function is not picking values from queries like:

```
DELETE FROM view_registered WHERE student = 4002222222 AND course = 'ITC222';
```

In fact, the output of it starts with `NOTICE:  Student: <NULL>, course: <NULL>.`

I can't understand what's wrong with this code and why the function picks the values from queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `OLD`:

```
RAISE NOTICE 'Student: %, course: %.', OLD.student, OLD.course;
```

In a `delete` trigger, `OLD` is populated but `NEW` is not.

Comment: In case I run again that query, I'd like to have the RAISE EXCEPTION has output, but it's not working, the result that comes out is just 'DELETE 0'. I can't understand what's wrong.